# How do we remove ssh targets from Remote Explorer

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

The Remote Explorer sidebar has an obvious icon for adding new targets but I can't find an option for removing or editing a target.
In my case, servers' IPs change frequently so they just continue to add up in the sidebar with now way of cleaning it up.

Are the targets stored in a file somewhere that I can manually edit?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can remove or edit it by editing `.ssh/config` file. Hope this helps.

Comment: this does in fact work .... but its a very displeasing way to have to remove ssh remotes

Comment: Handy hint: If you put `Host myhost.com*` in your .ssh/config then SSH:Remote ignores it.

Comment: You can find out where your `.ssh/config` file is by going to the Remote.SSH settings

Comment: Where is this file? I cannot find it even in the Remote.SSH settings.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi usually in your home directory in a hidden ".ssh" folder.

Comment: Another handy hint: you could just comment out the host temporarily, then "Reload Window" from command palette (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P), that host will be gone.  Then you can uncomment if you still want to access that host from CLI, etc.  Good way to "reset" and remove a bunch of old projects you don't want to see in there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

remove it from /.ssh/config file. Which will reflect in Visual Studio Code remote explorer.

Comment: This is an incorrect copy of the correct answer.