# Where is the remote SSH config file for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to remove a remote SSH address from vscode.remote panel:

[image]

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957203/how-do-we-remove-ssh-targets-from-remote-explorer), I am looking for the config file, but cannot find it. Here is what I see in the settings:

[image]

where can I find the config file, so that I can remove the remote address?

Comment: can you also show and describe what you see in the panel and what you want to remove?

Comment: please list the full paths of the files you have looked at and what you saw in them.

Answer (score 1):

Either `c:\Users\<username>\.ssh\config` or `C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_config`. the Remote.SSH config file only includes custom paths.

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of ssh-configuration files in Remote Explorer:

1. Hover the mouse on the "SSH" line: a gear-button [image: Gear button] will appear on the right side of the panel
   [image: Open SSH Config File]
2. The gear-button will bring up a list of relevant configuration files - from here you can navigate to the necessary file
   [image]
3. You can also open that list through the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) - **Remote-SSH: Open SSH Configuration File**
   [image]

.. also see [Documentation > Remember hosts and advanced settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_remember-hosts-and-advanced-settings)